# CSS First-child in a Div element strange behavior

Tags: html, css

So here is my Code :

```css
.tagBoxContent p:first-child {
  color: blue;
}

.tagBoxContent p:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tagBoxContent">
  <a class="tagHeadline">with <span>'chat'</span> tagged articles</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
  <p>Integer ma</p>
</div>
```

Why first-child dont trigger to the p tag but the last child element do? and how can i call the first p tag in this without first-child or with working first-child? I researched a lot but do not find any duplicate with the same problem.

Comment: Because there is no :first-child <p> - the first child is an <a>. It will  work if you use first-of-type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `:first-child` and it's not the first child. Instead, use `:first-of-type`.

```css
.tagBoxContent p:first-of-type {
  color: blue;
}

.tagBoxContent p:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tagBoxContent">
  <a class="tagHeadline">with <span>'chat'</span> tagged articles</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
  <p>Integer ma</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly, because p is not first-child

Comment: thanks , dont know that u can do it with first-of-type, greets :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-child()` to select a child not the first or last child

```css
.tagBoxContent p:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}

.tagBoxContent p:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tagBoxContent">
  <a class="tagHeadline">with <span>'chat'</span> tagged articles</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
  <p>Integer ma</p>
</div>
```